# Can I use biblatex to produce processed tex file for use with pandoc?

Tags: biblatex, biber, pandoc

I'm using biblatex (actually biblatex-chicago) with biber to process citations in an academic paper. Unfortunately I need to provide a Word file for a stage in the editorial process. I know that pandoc can use Bibtex refs and citeproc to create a bibliography, but it has a different syntax, and I don't want to set up the document to do that if I'm going to use biblatex in the end, and citeproc doesn't allow the same control that biblatex does.

So what I'd like to do is use biblatex as usual, but to produce a modified tex file rather than a pdf. I would then use pandoc to turn the tex into a docx file. Where my original tex file would have citation commands such as:

`\cite{XXX2000}`

the processed tex file would have commands to typeset the citation:

`(XXX, 2000)`

I imagine this is an intermediate stage in the biblatex/biber process.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE

Thanks to the comments below, I have solved this problem by using tex4ht.

A simple introduction to its use is here: 
https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial

Note: to use tex4ht with latest versions of biblatex, you need to update one of the tex4ht files, biblatex.4ht. Details here:
http://cvr.cc/?p=901#comment-16733

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've usually relied on some reasonable PDF->Word converter for things like this - some are quite good.

Comment: You might find better luck with `tex4ht` to get `.odt` and then save as `.docx`.  Pandoc is great until you start dealing with complex `.tex` files.

Comment: Thanks. @jon, that's very helpful - I hadn't heard of that. I'm using arara with Texshop, do you know if tex4ht can be called from within that?

Comment: @JonMair -- I'm afraid I know nothing about Texshop. I'm strictly emacs....

Comment: @jon Thanks again for the tip about tex4ht -- I can use it with Texshop and arara, not that that's essential.

Comment: @jon Thanks again for the tip about tex4ht -- I can use it with Texshop and arara, not that that's essential. It looks as though it's going to be very helpful...but now I have another problem. I'm running (1) lualatex, biber, biber, then (2) lualatex, mk4ht oolatex, htlatex. The second set of commands give pdf, odt, and html respectively, as you know. I've tried all three commands under (2) and I've tried just running each of those commands on their own. Pdf works fine, but the other two compile everything except anything produced by biblatex. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: PS - I was wrong to say that nothing from biblatex was captured...mk4ht and htlatex are capturing the bibliography title 'References', which is generated by \printbibliography, but nothing else.

Comment: PPS - got it working by updating the biblatex.4ht file with a new version from here: http://cvr.cc/?p=901

Comment: Can you post this as an answer and close the question as solved?

Comment: Have answered, but I can't see how to close it - could you point me in the right direction, please? I've searched in help but can't find it. Sorry, I'm sure it's very simple! This is my first stackexchange post!

Comment: I clicked on the tick and I think that's what you mean, but let me know if not. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments below, I have solved this problem by using tex4ht.

A simple introduction to its use is here: https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial

Note: to use tex4ht with latest versions of biblatex, you need to update one of the tex4ht files, biblatex.4ht. Details here: http://cvr.cc/?p=901#comment-16733

An extra tip: (Calling the command through Texshop) I found the tex4ht command often returned errors, but trashing auxiliary files and rerunning it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your source document, you should also be able to get a decent result with pandoc when converting directly from .tex to .docx.
Pick an appropriate Chicago-style from the [Zotero style repo](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=chicago) and convert your file with 
`pandoc -s -S --csl=Chicago_foo.csl --bibliography=foo.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc your_document.tex -o my_submission.docx`. 
As indicated your mileage may vary, make sure you have the latest pandoc installed (1.16.0.2).

Comment: Thanks -- I really like pandoc, but citeproc doesn't deal with referencing with enough precision for my purposes. I find it doesn't capitalize properly for example. For publishers I need to be able to give them things in exactly the format they specify. Maybe that's a csl problem, but for whatever reason, having tried with a number of different syles, I always seem to have small problems.

Comment: Yes, the challenge is more to choose a suitable style file (csl) that matches the needed output.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to submit a Word file for a stage in the editorial process, I decided to use a secondary, or rudimentary option. I compiled my tex project in PDF, then opened it in Adobe Acrobat DC. This software has a powerful export feature to xdoc. So it worked fine, I was surprised.